# no answer from simple subtraction code in C

Tags: c, math

i wrote code, and it gives me answers like 0.00 and 1.00, not actual math answer. Where i made mistake? (im begginer, dont scream on me :) )

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int a,b;
        float x;// score
    // Request 1
        printf("Zadanie 1(12)\n");
// Calculate the square root of the given interval
        printf("Oblicz pierwiastek rownania w podanym przedziale\n");
    // Give me a number a
        printf("Podaj liczbe a:\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
    // Give me a number b
        printf("Podaj liczbe b:\n");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            x=&a-&b;
//answer
            printf("%f", x);
            system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you're substracting the addresses: `x=&a-&b;`. Do `x=a-b;` `&a-&b` is probably -1 or 1 with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Subtract values like `x = a-b;`

Comment: Obviously you don't understand what the `&` before a variable name means. You should read your C textbook.

Answer (score 3):

```
    x = a - b
```

not

```
    x = &a - &b
```

Explanation:  The `&` operator gives you the memory address of `a`, which you need to give to scanf, so that it can place data there.  But you do math on the actual value of `a`.. which is just `a`.

Answer (score 0):

because of pointer arithmetic:

```
x = &a - &b;
```

computes the distance between the addresses of `a` and `b`, which are probably close since they're auto variables of the same type declared close-by. My guess is that you could get `1` or `-1` (or any other integer value but not `0` since `a` and `b` are located in 2 separate addresses) then put in a `float`.

(the difference of addresses of 2 consecutive integers is 1, independently of the size of the integer)

You need of course to do:

```
x = a - b;
```

You've been misled by the fact that `scanf` needs a *pointer* on `a` or `b` to be able to write a value when reading the input.